# Fast calculation of CDF / rolling join on multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to measure the empirical cumulative distribution of some data in a multivariate setting. That is, given a dataset like

```
library(data.table)  # v 1.9.7

set.seed(2016)
dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(1000), y=rnorm(1000), z=rnorm(1000))
dt
             x        y       z
   1: -0.91474  2.07025 -1.7499
   2:  1.00125 -1.80941 -1.3856
   3: -0.05642  1.58499  0.8110
   4:  0.29665 -1.16660  0.3757
   5: -2.79147 -1.75526  1.2851
  ---                          
 996:  0.63423  0.13597 -2.3710
 997:  0.21415  1.03161 -1.5440
 998:  1.15357 -1.63713  0.4191
 999:  0.79205 -0.56119  0.6670
1000:  0.19502 -0.05297 -0.3288
```

I want to count the number of samples such that (x <= X, y <= Y, z <= Z) for some grid of (X, Y, Z) upper bounds like

```
bounds <- CJ(X=seq(-2, 2, by=.1), Y=seq(-2, 2, by=.1), Z=seq(-2, 2, by=.1))
bounds
        X  Y    Z
    1: -2 -2 -2.0
    2: -2 -2 -1.9
    3: -2 -2 -1.8
    4: -2 -2 -1.7
    5: -2 -2 -1.6
   ---           
68917:  2  2  1.6
68918:  2  2  1.7
68919:  2  2  1.8
68920:  2  2  1.9
68921:  2  2  2.0
```

Now, I've figured out that I can elegantly do this (using non-equi joins)

```
dt[, Count := 1]
result <- dt[bounds, on=c("x<=X", "y<=Y", "z<=Z"), allow.cartesian=TRUE][, list(N.cum = sum(!is.na(Count))), keyby=list(X=x, Y=y, Z=z)]
result[, CDF := N.cum/nrow(dt)]
result
        X  Y    Z N.cum   CDF
    1: -2 -2 -2.0     0 0.000
    2: -2 -2 -1.9     0 0.000
    3: -2 -2 -1.8     0 0.000
    4: -2 -2 -1.7     0 0.000
    5: -2 -2 -1.6     0 0.000
   ---                       
68917:  2  2  1.6   899 0.899
68918:  2  2  1.7   909 0.909
68919:  2  2  1.8   917 0.917
68920:  2  2  1.9   924 0.924
68921:  2  2  2.0   929 0.929
```

But this method is really inefficient and gets very slow as I start increasing the bin count.  I think a multivariate version of `data.table`'s rolling join functionality would do the trick, but that's not possible to my knowledge. Any suggestions to speed this up?

Comment: I get what looks like an integer overflow error when I run your `result <- dt[` line

Comment: What version of data.table are you using?

Comment: just looking at that now. I'm using 1.9.6 which might be the issue...

Comment: Yes, you need 1.9.7 for non-equi joins.  Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
# Step1 - map each sample to the nearest X, Y, and Z above it. (In other words, bin the data.)

X <- data.table(X=seq(-2, 2, by=.1)); X[, x := X]
Y <- data.table(Y=seq(-2, 2, by=.1)); Y[, y := Y]
Z <- data.table(Z=seq(-2, 2, by=.1)); Z[, z := Z]

dt <- X[dt, on="x", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
dt <- Y[dt, on="y", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
dt <- Z[dt, on="z", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]

# Step2 - aggregate by unique (X, Y, Z) triplets and count the samples directly below each of these bounds.
bg <- dt[, .N, keyby=list(X, Y, Z)]

# Step4 - Get the count of samples directly below EVERY (X, Y, Z) bound
bounds <- CJ(X=X$X, Y=Y$Y, Z=Z$Z)
kl <- bg[bounds, on=c("X", "Y", "Z")]
kl[is.na(N), N := 0]

# Step5 (the tricky part) - Consider a single (Y, Z) pair. X will be in ascending order. So we can do a cumsum on X for each (Y, Z) to count x <= X | Y,Z. Now if you hold X and Z fixed, you can do a cumsum on Y (which is also in ascending order) to count x <= X, y <= Y | Z. And then just continue this process.
kl[, CountUntil.XgivenYZ := cumsum(N), by=list(Y, Z)]
kl[, CountUntil.XYgivenZ := cumsum(CountUntil.XgivenYZ), by=list(X, Z)]
kl[, CountUntil.XYZ := cumsum(CountUntil.XYgivenZ), by=list(X, Y)]

# Cleanup
setnames(kl, "CountUntil.XYZ", "N.cum")
kl[, CDF := N.cum/nrow(dt)]
```

---

## Generalization

For anyone who wants it, I generalized this to work with any number of variables and dumped the function into my R package, [mltools](https://github.com/ben519/mltools).

For example, to solve this problem you can do

```
library(mltools)

bounds <- list(x=seq(-2, 2, by=.1), y=seq(-2, 2, by=.1), z=seq(-2, 2, by=.1))
empirical_cdf(x=dt, ubounds=bounds)
        x  y    z N.cum   CDF
    1: -2 -2 -2.0     0 0.000
    2: -2 -2 -1.9     0 0.000
    3: -2 -2 -1.8     0 0.000
    4: -2 -2 -1.7     0 0.000
    5: -2 -2 -1.6     0 0.000
   ---                       
68917:  2  2  1.6   899 0.899
68918:  2  2  1.7   909 0.909
68919:  2  2  1.8   917 0.917
68920:  2  2  1.9   924 0.924
68921:  2  2  2.0   929 0.929
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Below, I have provided a general `base R` solution (it will work on non-uniform grids). It <s>is</s> was faster than the fastest published solution provided by the OP (more on this later). As the OP intimates, generating the `N.cum` column is the real bottleneck, so I focused my efforts on this task alone (i.e. generating `CDF` is a trivial task once `N.cum` is obtained).

```
JoeBase <- function(dtt, s) {
    m <- matrix(c(dtt$x, dtt$y, dtt$z), ncol = 3)
    N.Cum <- array(vector(mode = "integer"), dim = rev(sapply(s, length)))
    for (i in seq_along(s[[1]])) {
        t1 <- m[,1] <= s[[1]][i]
        for (j in seq_along(s[[2]])) {
            t2 <- t1 & (m[,2] <= s[[2]][j])
            for (k in seq_along(s[[3]])) {
                N.Cum[k,j,i] <- sum(t2 & (m[,3] <= s[[3]][k]))
            }
        }
    }
    as.vector(N.Cum)
}
```

The above algorithm takes advantage of vectorized operations, notably the creation and utilization of the logical vectors `t1` and `t2`. This vector is used to obtain the number of rows that met the criteria for all 3 columns in the original data.table. We simply rely on the internal coercion by R from a logical vector to an integral vector by the action of `sum`.

Figuring out how to populate the 3-dimensional integer array `N.Cum` was a bit of a challenge, as it is later going to be converted to a vector via `as.vector`. This took a bit of trial and error to learn how `as.vector` behaves. To my surprise, the "last" and "first" dimension must be permuted in order for the coercion to a vector to take place faithfully (The first few times through, I had N.Cum[i,j,k] instead of N.Cum[k,j,i]).

First, lets test equality:

```
library(data.table)
## Here is the function I used to test against. I included the generation
## of "bounds" and "bg" as "result" depends on both of these (N.B. "JoeBase" does not)
BenDT <- function(dt, s) {
    X <- data.table(X=s[[1]]); X[, x := X]
    Y <- data.table(Y=s[[2]]); Y[, y := Y]
    Z <- data.table(Z=s[[3]]); Z[, z := Z]

    dt <- X[dt, on="x", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
    dt <- Y[dt, on="y", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
    dt <- Z[dt, on="z", roll=-Inf, nomatch=0]
    bg <- dt[, .N, keyby=list(X, Y, Z)]

    bounds <- CJ(X=X$X, Y=Y$Y, Z=Z$Z)

    kl <- bg[bounds, on=c("X", "Y", "Z")]
    kl[is.na(N), N := 0]

    # Counting
    kl[, CountUntil.XgivenYZ := cumsum(N), by=list(Y, Z)]
    kl[, CountUntil.XYgivenZ := cumsum(CountUntil.XgivenYZ), by=list(X, Z)]
    kl[, CountUntil.XYZ := cumsum(CountUntil.XYgivenZ), by=list(X, Y)]

    # Cleanup
    setnames(kl, "CountUntil.XYZ", "N.cum")
    kl[, CDF := N.cum/nrow(dt)]
    kl
}

t1 <- BenDT(dt, seq(-2,2,0.1))
t2 <- JoeBase(dt, seq(-2,2,0.1))

all.equal(t1$N.cum, t2)
[1] TRUE
```

Now, we test for speed. First we will compile both functions using `cmpfun` from the `compiler` package. The first benchmark reflects the efficiency on smaller examples.

```
library(compiler)
c.JoeBase <- cmpfun(JoeBase)
c.BenDT <- cmpfun(BenDT)
c.OldBenDT <- cmpfun(OldBenDT)  ## The previous best solution that Ben contributed

st <- list(seq(-2, 2, 0.1), seq(-2, 2, 0.1), seq(-2, 2, 0.1))
microbenchmark(c.BenDT(dt, st), c.OldBenDT(dt, st), c.JoeBase(dt, st), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq       mean    median         uq        max neval cld
   c.BenDT(dt, st)   34.24872   34.78908   38.87775   37.4924   43.37179   46.12859    10 a  
c.OldBenDT(dt, st) 1485.68178 1532.35878 1607.96669 1593.9813 1619.58908 1845.75876    10  b 
 c.JoeBase(dt, st) 1880.71648 1962.38160 2049.43985 2007.4880 2169.93078 2281.02118    10   c
```

Below is the old test.
*However, when the number of bins increases, `c.JoeBase` really starts to dominate (over 5x faster).*

```
st <- list(seq(-5, 5, 0.1), seq(-5, 5, 0.1), seq(-5, 5, 0.1))
microbenchmark(c.JoeBase(dt, st), c.OldBenDT(dt, st), times = 5)
Unit: seconds
              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 c.JoeBase(dt, st)  23.50927  23.53809  29.61145  24.52748  30.81485  45.66759     5  a 
c.OldBenDT(dt, st) 110.60209 123.95285 133.74601 124.97929 125.96186 183.23394     5   b
```

After performing further tests, I have some misgivings about the results (@Ben has pointed out a similar sentiment in the comments). I'm pretty sure `c.JoeBase` appears to be faster only because of the limitations of my old computer.  As @stephematician pointed out in his answer, the original solution is memory intensive and if you were to simply perform a `system.time` on `c.OldBenDT`, you will see that the majority of the time is being spent in the `system` category and the `user` category is comparable to the `user` category of `c.JoeBase`. My 6 year old Mac has only 4GB of ram and I surmise that a lot of memory swaps are taking place with these operations.  Observe:

```
## test with very tiny buckets (i.e. 0.025 instead of 0.1 above)
st <- list(seq(-1.5, 1.5, 0.025), seq(-1.5, 1.5, 0.025), seq(-1.5, 1.5, 0.025))  
system.time(c.JoeBase(dt, st))
  user  system elapsed 
36.407   4.748  41.170

system.time(c.OldBenDT(dt, st))
   user  system elapsed 
49.653  77.954 475.304

system.time(c.BenDT(dt, st))  ## Ben's new solution is lightning fast
  user  system elapsed 
 0.603   0.063   0.668
```

Regardless, @Ben's latest solution is far superior. Check out these new benchmarks:

```
st <- list(seq(-5, 5, 0.1), seq(-5, 5, 0.1), seq(-5, 5, 0.1))
microbenchmark(c.JoeBase(dt, st), BenDT(dt, st), times = 5)
Unit: milliseconds
             expr        min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval cld
c.JoeBase(dt, st) 26517.0944 26855.7819 28341.5356 28403.7871 29926.213 30004.8018     5   b
    BenDT(dt, st)   342.4433   359.8048   400.3914   379.5319   423.336   496.8411     5  a
```

Yet another victory for `data.table`.

Comment: Nice - would it be easy to adapt this to deal with non-uniform grids?

Comment: @stephematician, Indeed, it can be adapted to deal with non-uniform grids. In fact, tomorrow I will update my answer to account for this.

Comment: @JosephWood if you could funnel the result back into a data.table format like mine, that would be very helpful.  Thanks

Comment: The re-ordering of the array dimensions is more 'the fault' of how `CJ(...)` works, rather than `as.vector`. The latter does the standard approach of flattening the dimensions in reverse. This ensures that, say, `as.vector(array(1:8, c(2,2,2)))` is the same as `1:8`.

Comment: @JosephWood hmm, can you retest your benchmarks? On my machine your method appears significantly slower, especially for something like `st <- seq(-2, 2, 0.02)`.  In fact, your timings are very close to mine but in reverse.

Comment: The timings are very helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just a note on the alternative, and yet, obvious solution:

```
set.seed(2016)
dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(20000), y=rnorm(20000), z=rnorm(20000))

system.time({
    dt <- t(as.matrix(dt))

    bounds <- as.matrix(expand.grid(z=seq(-2,2,0.1),
                                    y=seq(-2,2,0.1),
                                    x=seq(-2,2,0.1)))

    bounds <- bounds[,ncol(bounds):1]

    n_d <- ncol(bounds)

    x <- apply(bounds,
               1,
               function(x) sum(colSums(dt < x) == n_d))
})
```

This solution on my machine takes roughly twice as long to compute as JoeBase and OldBenDT solutions posted. The main difference? *Memory usage*. It is more *processor-bound*.

I don't know a precise way to compare memory usage in R, but the `memory.size(max=T)` function reported using 5Gb of memory for those previous approaches (not the non-equi-join approach), whilst only using 40Mb of memory for the `apply` approach (note: I used 20000 points in the sample distribution).

I think this has important implications for the scale of the computation you can execute.

Answer (score 0):

Should be faster compute the proportions and do the joins in one step so the intermediate results do not have to be materialized. Thanks for the comments, I edited corrections:

```
set.seed(2016)
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000), z = rnorm(1000))
setkey(dt)

bounds <- CJ(x = seq(-2, 2, by= .1 ), y = seq(-2, 2, by = .1), z = seq(-2, 2, by = .1))
n_rows_dt <- nrow(dt)

A <- dt[bounds, .N / n_rows_dt , on = c("x<=x","y<=y","z<=z"),
        by = .EACHI,
        allow.cartesian = T]
```

Comment: Just noticed a bug in my own code.  Please re-run my code.  You'll notice our answers don't match.  Also, your marginal CDF for X doesn't look right -`b[y == 2 & z == 2]`

Comment: Thanks, but still not right.  Notice your result for (x <= -2, y <= -1, z <= 2) is 0 but the correct answer should be 3.  Also, this method almost as slow as my own.

Comment: I can't speak to the speed of this approach yet, but by changing the on= argument to c("x<=x", "y<=y", "z<=z"), this does appear to give the correct answer. (That is, change "less than" to "less than or equal to")